# Images not loading in CodeIgniter, image path correct error 403

Tags: php, html, css

I have an application where I save the image path in the database. I have a method Uploads

```
function uploads($path) 
{
    echo base_url('application/uploads/'.$path);   
    return true;
}
```

//base url is $config['base_url'] = 'https://localhost/salon';

$path is taken from the image

```
 style="background-image: url(<?php uploads('gallery/'.$gImage['imgPath']);?>)"
```

This is how i set the background image.

The error I get is 403 forbidden access when I try to open the image.

I also tried echo out the src and this is what I get https://prnt.sc/16ofw1m

I don't know where that 1 at the end comes from but in src as seen in inspect element there is no 1   https://prnt.sc/16ogce3

Comment: Normally images are uploaded to the assets folder and you can access assets folder easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my htaccess file, I just commented out this lines>

```
#<IfModule authz_core_module>
#    Require all denied
#</IfModule>
#<IfModule !authz_core_module>
#    Deny from all
#</IfModule>
```

It took me a while to notice they were there.

Answer (score -2):

The  block you've provided is from an Apache configuration file and is related to the cgi-bin directory within your XAMPP installation. This particular block seems to be allowing all requests (Require all granted) to the cgi-bin directory and also enabling the use of .htaccess files (AllowOverride All).
file path apache/conf/https.conf
If you are encountering a "403 Forbidden" error when trying to access an image in a different directory (not the cgi-bin directory), the issue might not be related to the configuration shown in the block you provided. The cgi-bin directory is typically used for handling CGI scripts and might not be directly relevant to serving images.

To troubleshoot the "403 Forbidden" error for the image, you'll need to focus on the directory that contains the image, as well as the related configuration directives for that directory.

Here's a basic example of how you could configure access to a directory containing images:

apache

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project/writable/platedata/plateimage">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted

In this example, you should replace "C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project/writable/platedata/plateimage" with the actual path to the directory containing your images. The Options directive allows directory indexing and following symbolic links if needed. The AllowOverride None directive disables the use of .htaccess files within this directory.

Remember to restart your Apache server after making any changes to the configuration files for the changes to take effect.

If you're still facing issues after reviewing and adjusting the configuration for the directory containing your images, consider checking the error logs and using your browser's developer tools to gather more information about the "403 Forbidden" error. Additionally, consulting with experienced developers or server administrators can be helpful for resolving complex configuration issues.

Comment: Did you create this with [chatgpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)? Furthermore, I have no clue why you are talking about `XAMPP`, there is no information given that OP is using `XAMPP` nor is it tagged as such